# How to paginate a list of gallery items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am displaying all videos that are available in my gallery in my flutter app. First, I am fetching all the videos list, and then generating thumbnails for the same. I am using this line to display all the videos:

```
var files = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera").listSync();
```

Due to having too many videos, it is taking a lot of time to open. Is there any way that, I can paginate this data?

Like, when I click on my button, to open the list of videos, it takes a lot of time to navigate. I am calling my page like this:

```
if(context.mounted) {
      res = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>const VideoSelectionPage()));
    }
```

and inside my initstate, I am calling the line above to fetch my videos list. Why is it taking time to navigate, I mean it would be alright if it took time after navigating and loading the data.

So, I want to decrease time for both, navigating as well as when loading images for the videos. I think pagination might help me.

Some snippets of my code if it helps:

```
List<FileSystemEntity> videosList = [];
int m=0;
final dimension = (ScreenSize.screenWidth-20)/2;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    videosList = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera").listSync().where((element) => checkType(element.path)).toList();
  }



Future<Uint8List?> _generateThumbnail(String path) async {
    final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
      video: path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      quality: 100,
    );
    return uint8list;
  }

  bool checkType(String path) {
    String? mimeStr = lookupMimeType(path);
    List<String>? fileType = mimeStr?.split('/');
    return fileType?.contains('video')??false;
  }

  Widget getItems(int index) {
    if(index<m) {
      return FutureBuilder<Uint8List?>(
        future: _generateThumbnail(videosList[index].path),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return ShimmerWidget(
              height: dimension,
              width: dimension,
              shapeBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error generating thumbnail');
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
            return const Text('Thumbnail not available');
          } else {
            return VideoFileCard(
              uInt8list: snapshot.data!,
              file: videosList[index],
              dimension: dimension,
              savedPath: (path) {
                if(path!=null && path.isNotEmpty) {
                  Navigator.pop(context, path);
                }
              },
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
    else {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }

..............

body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
              Row(
                children: [
                  getItems(i),
                  getItems(i+1),
                ],
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I am thinking that maybe when i am storing data in my videos list, calling `toList()` might be adding more time for process, as it makes another copy and gives it to variable.

PS: I can't use gridview/gridview.builder, because it was rebuilding and destroying objects as soon as you scroll, I tried everything so I had to use Column and for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve it using `list()` method instead of `listSync()` becuase the former returns a `Stream` in which case it doesn't block the user from interacting with app.

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html):

> I/O operations can block a program for some period of time while it waits for the operation to complete. To avoid this, all methods involving I/O have an asynchronous variant which returns a Future. This future completes when the I/O operation finishes. While the I/O operation is in progress, the Dart program is not blocked, and can perform other operations.

So the final result will be:

```
final dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera');
dir.list(recursive: true).listen(
  (event) {
    //Do stuff.
  },
);
```

---

## The full code

Home page state:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final StreamController<bool> streamController = StreamController();

  List<FileSystemEntity> videos = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Permission.storage.request().then(
      (value) {
        if (value.isGranted) {
          final dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera');

          dir.list(recursive: true).listen(
            (event) {
              if (checkType(event.path)) {
                videos.add(event);
                streamController.add(true);
              }
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  bool checkType(String path) {
    String? mimeStr = lookupMimeType(path);
    List<String>? fileType = mimeStr?.split('/');
    return fileType?.contains('video') ?? false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: streamController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
            ),
            itemCount: videos.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return VideoTile(path: videos[index].path);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Video tile widget:

```
class VideoTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoTile({
    super.key,
    required this.path,
  });

  final String path;

  @override
  State<VideoTile> createState() => _VideoTileState();
}

class _VideoTileState extends State<VideoTile>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  bool isLoading = true;
  Uint8List? image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    generateThumbnail(widget.path);
  }

  void generateThumbnail(String path) async {
    print('get video thumbnail');
    image = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
      video: path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      quality: 100,
    );
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final image = this.image;

    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : image != null
              ? Image.memory(image)
              : const Icon(
                  Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                ),
    );
  }

  @override
  get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It worked. Just asking, is there any way that I can show videos from sd card and storage together. Right now, I am displaying all videos of camera first, then all of sd card. Can they be mixed together at the time of loading them?

Comment: @ShreyanshSharma Just add another `Directory` object and listen for its content beside the first one.